# app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 68

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am new with PHP and Laravel.
I am using Laravel Framework version "laravel/framework": "5.4.*", and PHP 7.

I am building multilevel authentication.

I have been following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8T3MjZPDdI
Alexander Curtis videos.

Error which I am getting is:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$login' (T_VARIABLE) in app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 68

```
    $login = 'admin.login';
```

[Mon May  8 20:53:30 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Code is double check many times, from https://github.com/DevMarketer/multiauth_tutorial/archive/part_3.zip

I am using Laravel way to make auth, not any external package.
website /admin/login is showing blank page.

also webserver is php artisan serve.

I am stuck with this error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

 use Exception; use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException; use
 Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

 class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
     /**
      * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
      *
      * @var array
      */
     protected $dontReport = [
         \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
         \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
         \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
         \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
         \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
         \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
     ];


 /**
  * Report or log an exception.
  *
  * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
  *
  * @param  \Exception  $exception
  * @return void
  */
 public function report(Exception $exception)
 {
     parent::report($exception);
 }

 /**
  * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Exception  $exception
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
     return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }

 /**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated   
 * response.

  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
```

Second part of code where added multilogin part

```
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

    switch ($guard) {
      case 'admin':
        # code...
         $login = 'admin.login';
        break;

      default:
        # code...
       $login ='login';
        break;
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove the default sublime text suggestions:
So remove the "# code ... " before your $login declaration.

```
  switch ($guard) {
      case 'admin':
        *# code...*
         $login = 'admin.login';
        break;

      default:
        *# code...*
       $login ='login';
        break;
    }
```